# Honda Oil Pan in winter cold

Tags: honda, winter, oil-pan, sealant

Does anyone know if Hondabond gasket sealant can be applied in low temperatures?  I have to replace my Honda 3.5l oil pan due to cracking and cannot wait until temps moderate.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Read the label for any specific warnings about application temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

It ultimately depends on how cold it is. As jwh20 said, the label will likely say.

That said, I couldn't find an exact temp marked on the packaging for the HT stuff. However, it's a little anecdotal, but DAP 100% silicone sealant can be applied as low as -35F and as high as 140F. Since these sealants are "partial drying" types, it would be best not to go that cold.

I'll see if I can get something more specific.